# I cannot reboot my computer, when i try to i only see a black screen

Tags: boot, grub2, screen

Today i installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to my computer with dual boot. I used Ubuntu for couple hours. But after that i closed my computer and did not use it for a few hours.Now when push my computer's power button, only thing that i see is black screen and i can not do anything. So even i can not reach my main OS (Windows 8.1) also i can not reach Bios and boot manager etc. I tried several times to open my computer but always i see the same thing. I guess i should use only Windows OS. So how can i reach my Windows and erase Ubuntu&Grub Menu?

Comment: Try pressing CTRL+ALT+F3 and see if you can sign in from there. If this works, and after you sign in, you can either run `sudo reboot` or `sudo systemctl restart display-manager`. Also, this might be a problem with hibernating or sleeping so try to do a hard restart by holding the power key until it powers down and then try booting up again. Another thing to try is to try increasing the backlight if for some strange reason the backlight accidentally got set to 0.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried them but they did not work. For the first solution, do i have to start ubuntu from Grub Menu? Because i cannot start ubuntu i guess. Still all i see is just a black screen.

Comment: Nmath thanks, i checked that page earlier, also i checked again but unfortunately no, most of the answers says use an Usb Stick but i cannot reach boot manager. For the rest of the solutions they did not work.

Answer (score 0):

May I ask if this computer device of yours uses hard drive?  It could be an out of the blue chance that the hard drive failed at some point in time moments before closing the computer, after you used the Ubuntu for the first time.  I would also like to ask if it is an SSD and if so, how old is the SSD?  Even a hard drive/SSD end of life scenario, the BIOS may not work.  The reason being that in the case of an UEFI, the UEFI BIOS may be on the storage medium instead of on an integrated flash chip.  This is typically the case in cheap or computers that came out around the start of the Windows support for UEFI era.

It could be possible that the device had the wrong BIOS settings in the first place.    Take for example the scenario described on this support thread for the Lenovo ThinkPad P52.  The issue described is almost like the issue you are describing. https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Ubuntu/P52-Windows-10-dual-boot-Ubuntu-18-04-1/m-p/4160018?page=1#4186981 The thing is **you may need to have beforehand turned off secure boot and UEFI in the BIOS**.

A very unusual but possible thing could be your screen has gone bad.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do not think so there is a permanent damage in my hard disk. Because during this problem, i would be able to reach the windows earlier. You can check this video about that.(Sorry this video's purpose was just sending to my friend so it is not well recorded)  https://youtu.be/zpNbuJMX9Mg What i say in the video, when you push the power button the screen is just like that then i press two times down arrow and i press enter(Selecting Windows from the Grub Menu). After that Windows Login Menu came up. But unfortunately, the same thing does not work now.

Comment: By the way someone asked that _"A further question. When you installed Ubuntu did you install it in UEFI mode or legacy mode? If Windows is installed in UEFI mode then Ubuntu must be installed in UEFI mode. If Windows is installed in Legacy mode then Ubuntu must be installed in Legacy mode. Mixing the two modes could be what is causing this issue. "_ I guess his prediction may be right, because i didnt know about these modes, so my Windows is UEFI mode but i do not know about my ubuntu's mode. Probably my problem is causing because of this.

Comment: I've removed that portion.